# Can't Set Material Icon Color

Tags: css, angular-material

I have this html:

```
<i class="material-icons">
   cloud_upload
</i>
```

And this css:

```
.material-icons {
   font-size: 100px;
   color: mat-color($vp-blue) !important;
}
```

However, I'm unable to change the color of the icon? "mat-color($vp-blue)" works absolutely everywhere else in my app but here. If I add a style tag and set the color manually that works but I'd hate to resort to that. I tried adding another class to the icon to set the color but that didn't work either. I should note that the font-size is applied properly but not the color.

Edit:

I'm using a angular material theme generated by this [site](http://mcg.mbitson.com/#!?mcgpalette0=%233f51b5).

For whatever reason my blue color isn't being pulled in to my SCSS file. However, another color pulled from the same file is working... I added a reference to the color I actually want and it works as expected. I'm including my theme.scss file for reference.

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';
@include mat-core();

// #EB3D53
// #4980b3
//background-color: #FBFBFB;

// this works
$vp-blue-simple: #4980b3;

$vp-blue: (
  50: #e9f0f6,
  100: #c8d9e8,
  200: #a4c0d9,
  300: #80a6ca,
  400: #6493be,
  500: #4980b3,
  600: #4278ac,
  700: #396da3,
  800: #31639a,
  900: #21508b,
  A100: #c8dfff,
  A200: #95c1ff,
  A400: #62a4ff,
  A700: #4895ff,
  contrast: (
    50: $dark-primary-text,
    100: $dark-primary-text,
    200: $dark-primary-text,
    300: $dark-primary-text,
    400: $dark-primary-text,
    500: $dark-primary-text,
    600: $dark-primary-text,
    700: $dark-primary-text,
    800: $dark-primary-text,
    900: $light-primary-text,
    A100: $dark-primary-text,
    A200: $dark-primary-text,
    A400: $dark-primary-text,
    A700: $dark-primary-text,
  )
);

/* For use in src/lib/core/theming/_palette.scss */
$vp-red: (
    50 : #fde8ea,
    100 : #f9c5cb,
    200 : #f59ea9,
    300 : #f17787,
    400 : #ee5a6d,
    500 : #eb3d53,
    600 : #e9374c,
    700 : #e52f42,
    800 : #e22739,
    900 : #dd1a29,
    A100 : #ffffff,
    A200 : #ffdddf,
    A400 : #ffaaaf,
    A700 : #ff9098,
    contrast: (
        50 : #000000,
        100 : #000000,
        200 : #000000,
        300 : #000000,
        400 : #000000,
        500 : #ffffff,
        600 : #ffffff,
        700 : #ffffff,
        800 : #ffffff,
        900 : #ffffff,
        A100 : #000000,
        A200 : #000000,
        A400 : #000000,
        A700 : #000000,
    )
);

$vp-app-primary: mat-palette($vp-blue);
$vp-app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-pink, 500, 900, A100);
$vp-app-warn:    mat-palette($vp-red);

$vp-app-theme: mat-light-theme($vp-app-primary, $vp-app-accent, $vp-app-warn);
@include angular-material-theme($vp-app-theme);
```

Edit2:

Apologies the color that is working is the $vp-app-warn. My question is why this would be happening in this particular situation. $vp-blue-simple works just fine yet using mat-color($vp-blue) does not. I could not find an angular-material-theme tag or anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

This question cannot be answered without seeing your overall HTML structure. It's possible to fix, without resorting to `!important` by specifying a unique element higher up the HTML tree to make the selector *more specific*, such as:

```
.material-icons, #mysection .material-icons {
   font-size: 100px;
   color: mat-color($vp-blue)
}
```

See: http://cssspecificity.com/ on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your response.This helped me look a little deeper and apparently my color for this particular element was coming back as blank.